# Install Wine as root In Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-12.04

I want to install wine as root. But in terminal it's saying it is not recommended to do so. What if I install it as root and how do I bypass this error message in terminal

**Output when I try to install wine as root from terminal:**

***$ ./tools/wineinstall***

***Wine Installer v1.0***

***You are running wineinstall as root, this is not advisable. Please rerun as a user.***

***Aborting.***

Answer (score 1):

Linux usually have a behavior, that for any new installation root permission is required. For installing the wine in Ubuntu use the following command - `sudo apt-get install wine1.2`.

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Go to software centre and search *wine* .
2. select "Wine Windows Program Loader" and install it.
3. After installing wine -> select any .exe file and its open with wine. it is automatically installing.